# R binary indicator matrix for items in a transaction

Tags: r, matrix, transactions, binary

Suppose you have a data frame of two columns - TransactionId and ItemId and it looks like this

```
A a
A b
A c
A e
B a
B d
B e
```

etc

and you would like to represent it as a matrix which looks like:

```
   a b c d e f 
A  1 1 1 0 1 0 
B  1 0 0 1 1 0
```

etc

What is most elegant way of doing it? I have heard of model.matrix but do believe it's for data with a single row per transaction only.

Derrick

Comment: Yes, `model.matrix` is not exactly useful here, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the read.transactions function in arules package with: format="single"

> data <- read.transactions("YourDataset.csv", format = "single", sep=",", cols = c(1,2))

Then you can format your dataset using the "as" function as follow:

> as(data[1:5], "list")
>
> as(data[1:5], "matrix")
>
> as(data[1:5], "ngCMatrix")

Here are some tutorials:

http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs445/misc/mar13lae08.pdf

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/arules/docs/nitems

Hope that helps.

Karim